# Programatically mimic CTRL+A in a DataGrid in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I need to select an entire DataGrid like the keystroke CTRL+A. For example: instead of selecting the datagrid with the mouse, the user just clicks a button and the datagrid is selected.
 Is it possible?

Comment: Why not provide a link so that users can download the contents of the datagrid as a CSV or Excel file?

Comment: What do you mean "select".  You want it to be the users cursor to automatically select it on their browser?

Comment: Do you want the UI aspects (highlighting, etc.) as well as all records selected as far as the server is concerned or just want to be able to press a button or something to work all DataGrid items at the same time?  What do you mean by mimicking the "Select All (ctrl+a)"?  What events or changes are you trying to accomplish when someone hits Ctrl+A or clicks on a button that says "select all"?  Please supply more information on what you are actually trying to accomplish so we can provide better solutions and not assume we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to press a button to select all DataGrid items in the user´s browser. Something like CTRL+A or the selection of a portion of a text with the mouse.

Comment: So you want to highlight all rows?  Just UI aspects and not anything on the server?  Just changing the background color of the cells (in essence)?

Comment: Yes, just highlight the rows so the user can copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't imagine the purpose of something like this, it sounds like you'll need to use javascript for this.  Add a button/link to the page and then use something like [this script](http://codingtricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/javascript-select-or-highlight-text.html) to highlight/select all the text within the DataGrid.